# When was the last time Superman's 'electro-chemical aura' was mentioned in comics?

Tags: dc, comics, superman

When John Byrne started writing *Superman* comics after the continuity reboot in 1986, he established that Clark's body was surrounded by an invisible 'electro-chemical aura', which prevented any fabric worn close to his skin from tearing or getting dirty. The aura was first alluded to (though not mentioned by name) in [*Man of Steel* #1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/The_Man_of_Steel_Vol_1) (published in 1986).

[image]

I'd like to establish the *most recent* reference to this aura within a comic, if possible, as I'm curious to know how long this concept was maintained for.